# Remove Columns from DataFrame based on Standard Deviation

Tags: python, dataframe, standard-deviation

I am trying to do something that I think should be rather simple but I am stuck.

I would like to be able to get the standard deviation of each column in my dataframe and remove that column if the standard deviation is below a set number. This is as far as I have gotten.

```
stdev_min = 0.6
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
namelist = list(df.columns.values.tolist()) 
stdev = pd.DataFrame(df.std())
```

I've tried a few things but nothing worth mentioning, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have asked 9 questions so far on Stack Overflow. You have not accepted any answer for the other 8. Please consider acknowledging the answers fellow members provide you. It helps to recognize people for their efforts.

Comment: `df.loc[:, df.std() < threshold]`?

Comment: @PaulH, OP is looking to remove a column based on std of the column.

Comment: @JoeFerndz, that's what that does (though I got the direction of the chevron wrong)

Comment: Yea. you are correct. This is much better than iterating thru the columns

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any loops.
You rarely do with pandas.
In this case, you need boolean indexing:

```py
import pandas
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(37)

stdev_min = 0.95
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(20, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
```

So now `df.std()` gives me:

```
A    0.928547
B    0.859394
C    0.998692
D    1.187380
E    1.092970
dtype: float64
```

so I can do

```py
df.loc[:, df.std() > stdev_min]
```

And get:

```
       C     D     E
0   0.35 -1.30  1.52
1  -0.45  0.96 -0.83
2   0.52 -0.06 -0.03
3   1.89  0.40  0.19
4  -0.27 -2.07 -0.71
5  -1.72 -0.40  1.27
6   0.44 -2.05 -0.23
7   1.76  0.06  0.36
8  -0.30 -2.05  1.68
9   0.34  1.26 -1.08
10  0.10 -0.48 -1.74
11  1.95 -0.08  1.51
12  0.43 -0.06 -0.63
13 -0.30 -1.06  0.57
14 -0.95 -1.45  0.93
15 -1.13  2.23 -0.88
16 -0.77  0.86  0.58
17  0.93 -0.11 -1.29
18 -0.82  0.03 -0.44
19  0.40  1.13 -1.89
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this.

Iterate through each column. Get the Standard Deviation for the column. Check if it is less than the minimum standard deviation value. If it is, drop the column using inplace=True

```
stdev_min = 0.6
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
for col in df.columns:
    print (col, df[col].std())
    if df[col].std() < stdev_min:
        df.drop(col,axis='columns', inplace=True)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
A 0.5046725928657507
B 1.1382221163449697
C 1.0318169576864502
D 0.7129102193331575
E 1.3805207184389312
```

The value of A is less than 0.6 and so it got dropped.

```
          B         C         D         E
0 -0.923822  1.155547 -0.601033 -0.066207
1  0.068844  0.426304 -0.376052  0.368574
2  0.585187 -0.367270  0.530934  0.086811
3  0.021466  1.381579  0.483134 -0.300033
4  0.351492 -0.648734 -0.736213  0.827953
5  0.155731 -0.004504  0.315432  0.310515
6 -1.092933  1.341933 -0.672240 -3.482960
7 -0.587766  0.227846  0.246781  1.978528
8  1.565055  0.527668 -0.371854 -0.030196
9 -2.634862 -1.973874  1.508080 -0.362073
```

Did a few more runs. Here's an example with before and after.

DF before

```
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.496740  0.799021  1.655287  0.091138  0.309186
1 -0.580667 -0.749337 -0.521909 -0.529410  1.010981
2  0.212731  0.126389 -2.244500  0.400540 -0.148761
3 -0.424375 -0.832478 -0.030865 -0.561107  0.196268
4  0.229766  0.688040  0.580294  0.941885  1.554929
5  0.676926 -0.062092 -1.452619  0.952388 -0.963857
6  0.683216  0.747429 -1.834337 -0.402467 -0.383881
7  0.834815 -0.770804  1.299346  1.694612  1.171190
8  0.500445 -1.517488  0.610287 -0.601442  0.343389
9 -0.182286 -0.713332  0.526507  1.042717  1.229628
```

Standard Deviations for each column of DF:

```
A 0.49088743174291477
B 0.8047513692231202
C 1.333382184686379
D 0.8248456756163864
E 0.8033725216710547
```

`df['A']` is less than `0.6` and so got dropped.

DF after dropping the column.

```
          B         C         D         E
0  0.799021  1.655287  0.091138  0.309186
1 -0.749337 -0.521909 -0.529410  1.010981
2  0.126389 -2.244500  0.400540 -0.148761
3 -0.832478 -0.030865 -0.561107  0.196268
4  0.688040  0.580294  0.941885  1.554929
5 -0.062092 -1.452619  0.952388 -0.963857
6  0.747429 -1.834337 -0.402467 -0.383881
7 -0.770804  1.299346  1.694612  1.171190
8 -1.517488  0.610287 -0.601442  0.343389
9 -0.713332  0.526507  1.042717  1.229628
```